# Dict of string and list in python dataclass

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python, especially for the dataclass syntax. Given the following minimal code running on pyhton 3.8:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, List

@dataclass
class TestData:
    @dataclass
    class TestInnerData:
        name: str = ""
        items: [int] = field(default_factory=[int])
        level: int = 0

    _id: str = ""
    name: str = ""
    groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]])
    #groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=dict)


data = TestData(name="test", groups={"xxx": [TestData.TestInnerData(level=2)]})
```

When I simply run it, it raises the following error:

```
data = TestData(name="test", groups={"xxx": [TestData.TestInnerData(level=2)]})
E   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

There is a different notion in the commented line, none of them works.

Can anybody point me, what did I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: items: list[int] = field(default_factory=list[int])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the default factory incorrectly except in one spot where you use `dict`. Mirror this pattern, because default_factory expects a function or callable:

```py
@dataclass
class TestData:
    @dataclass
    class TestInnerData:
        name: str = ""
        items: [int] = field(default_factory=list)
        level: int = 0

    _id: str = ""
    name: str = ""
    groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=dict)
    #groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=dict)
```

While we're at it, if you want a typed dictionary like this, you might want to use a `defaultdict` from collections:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

@dataclass
class TestData:
    @dataclass
    class TestInnerData:
        name: str = ""
        items: [int] = field(default_factory=list)
        level: int = 0

    _id: str = ""
    name: str = ""
    groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=lambda: defaultdict(list))
    #groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close :)

This is how you'd do it:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, List


@dataclass
class TestInnerData:
    name: str = ""
    items: [int] = field(default_factory=list)
    level: int = 0


@dataclass
class TestData:
    _id: str = ""
    name: str = ""
    groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]])


data = TestData(
    name="test",
    groups={"xxx": [TestInnerData(level=2)]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few mistakes:

- They way you are defining the typing for lists and dictionaries is incorrect. For example, `[int]` should be `List[int]` and `Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]]` should be used directly as the type, not as a default_factory.
- In your `TestInnerData` class, the items field is defined as a list of integers. But you provided a `default_factory` of `[int]`. It should be `list`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict, List

@dataclass
class TestData:
    @dataclass
    class TestInnerData:
        name: str = ""
        items: List[int] = field(default_factory=list)
        level: int = 0

    _id: str = ""
    name: str = ""
    groups: Dict[str, List[TestInnerData]] = field(default_factory=dict)

data = TestData(name="test", groups={"xxx": [TestData.TestInnerData(level=2)]})
```